# redirect handler python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am using urllib.request package to open and read webpages. I would like to make sure my code handles redirects well. Right now I just fail when I see a redirect (it is an HTTPError). Can someone guide me as to how to handle that? My code currently looks like:

```
try:
        text = str(urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=10).read())
except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
        print(error)
except urllib.error.URLError as error:
        print(error)
except timeout as error:
        print(error)
```

Please help me I am new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Describe the behavior you'd like to see when there's a redirect.

Comment: I would like it to instead of failing, go to the redirected page and read that webpage. Especially redirects from http to https to the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `requests` package I was able to find a better solution. With the only exception you need to handle are:

```
 try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout =5)

except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
# Maybe set up for a retry, or continue in a retry loop

except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects as error:
# Tell the user their URL was bad and try a different one

except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
# Connection could not be completed

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
# catastrophic error. bail.
```

And to get the text of that page, all you need to do is:
`r.text`

Answer (score 0):

I use special URLopener to catch redirects:

```
import urllib

class RedirectException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, errcode, newurl):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.errcode = errcode
        self.newurl = newurl

class MyURLopener(urllib.URLopener):
    # Error 301 -- relocated (permanently)
    def http_error_301(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data=None):
        if headers.has_key('location'):
            newurl = headers['location']
        elif headers.has_key('uri'):
            newurl = headers['uri']
        else:
            newurl = "Nowhere"
        raise RedirectException(errcode, newurl)

    # Error 302 -- relocated (temporarily)
    http_error_302 = http_error_301
    # Error 303 -- relocated (see other)
    http_error_303 = http_error_301
    # Error 307 -- relocated (temporarily)
    http_error_307 = http_error_301

urllib._urlopener = MyURLopener()
```

Now I need to catch RedirectException and voila — I know there was a redirect and I know the URL. Warning — I use the code with Python 2.7, don't know if it will work with Python 3.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for Python 3... thanks for the response though